# How to replace a long chain of if

Tags: java, oop, enums

I have an object containing 3 integers i, j and k.

Those integers can have a minus sign (M), a plus sign (P) or be null (O).

Any such object can thus be classified in one of those categories:
MMM, MMP, MPM, MPP, PMM, PMP, PPM, PPP, OMM, OMP, OPM, OPP, MOM, MOP, POM, POP, MMO, MPO, PMO, PPO, MOO, POO, OMO, OPO, OOM, OOP, OOO.

I want to perform a computation on objects of this type that will differ depending on the category of the objet.

My object does not only contain those three integers, but other information that will be used in the computation.

My two questions are:

- How to deduce the category of the object from its i, j and k values?
- How to implement the selection of the proper algorithm?

I made a naive implementation that uses enums and a lot of if...else, but I am not satisfied with the result, especially the if...else part.

Any better, more object-oriented idea?

The Data class:

```
public class Data {
    private int i, j, k;
    private double otherData;
    private Category category;

    public void init(int i, int j, int k) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
        this.k = k;

        if (i < 0) {
            if (j < 0) {
                if (k < 0) {
                    category = Category.MMM;
                } else if (k > 0) {
                    category = Category.MMP;
                } else//(k >= 0)
                {
                    category = Category.MMO;
                }
            } else//(j >= 0)
            {
                if (k < 0) {
                    category = Category.MPM;
                    if (j == 0)
                        category = Category.MOM;
                } else//(k >= 0)
                {
                    if ((j == 0) && (k == 0))
                        category = Category.MOO;
                    else if (k == 0)
                        category = Category.MPO;
                    else if (j == 0)
                        category = Category.MOP;
                    else
                        category = Category.MPP;
                }
            }
        } else//(i >= 0)
        {
            if (j < 0) {
                if (k < 0) {
                    category = Category.PMM;
                    if (i == 0)
                        category = Category.OMM;
                } else//(k >= 0)
                {
                    if ((i == 0) && (k == 0))
                        category = Category.OMO;
                    else if (k == 0)
                        category = Category.PMO;
                    else if (i == 0)
                        category = Category.OMP;
                    else
                        category = Category.PMP;
                }
            } else//(j >= 0)
            {
                if (k < 0) {
                    if ((i == 0) && (j == 0))
                        category = Category.OOM;
                    else if (i == 0)
                        category = Category.OPM;
                    else if (j == 0)
                        category = Category.POM;
                    else
                        category = Category.PPM;
                } else//(k > 0)
                {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        if (j == 0)
                            category = Category.OOP;
                        else if (k == 0)
                            category = Category.OPO;
                        else
                            category = Category.OPP;
                    } else {
                        if ((j == 0) && (k == 0))
                            category = Category.POO;
                        else if (j == 0)
                            category = Category.POP;
                        else if (k == 0)
                            category = Category.PPO;
                        else
                            category = Category.PPP;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void computeSomething() {
        category.computeSomething(this);
    }

    public double getOtherData() {
        return otherData;
    }

    public void setOtherData(double otherData) {
        this.otherData = otherData;
    }
}
```

The enum class:

```
public enum Category {
    MMM {
        @Override
        public void computeSomething(Data data) {
            // Do something
        }
    },
    MMP {
        @Override
        public void computeSomething(Data data) {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
    // Omitted code for clarity

    public abstract void computeSomething(Data data);
}
```

For the full use case context, see See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.147.2010&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is equivalent to your init method:

```
public void init(int i, int j, int k) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.k = k;
    category=Category.valueOf( (i<0?"M":(i==0?"O":"P"))
                              +(j<0?"M":(j==0?"O":"P"))
                              +(k<0?"M":(k==0?"O":"P")));
}
```

---

As suggested by @Robert, you can also do this :

```
private void init(int i, int j, int k){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.k = k;
    category = Category.fromInts(i,j,k);
}

enum Category {
        MMM, MMP, MPM, MPP, PMM, PMP, PPM, PPP, 
        OMM, OMP, OPM, OPP, MOM, MOP, POM, POP, 
        MMO, MPO, PMO, PPO, MOO, POO, OMO, OPO, 
        OOM, OOP, OOO;

        static Category fromInts(int i, int j, int k){
            return Category.valueOf( (i<0?"M":(i==0?"O":"P"))
                                    +(j<0?"M":(j==0?"O":"P"))
                                    +(k<0?"M":(k==0?"O":"P")));
        };
}
```

---

Regarding selection of computation algorithm, it's probably a good idea to remove it from the enum and go for something like this :

```
public class Data {
    ...
    public void computeSomething() {
        swith(category){
            case MMM : computeMMM();break;
            case MMO : computeMMO();break;
            ...
        }
    }

    private void computeMMM(){
        ...
    }

    private void computeMMO(){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You could even push that magic into the enum itself, e.g., into a static `fromInts(int i, int j, int k)` method, and DRY up the comparison code in another (private static) method.

Comment: I prefer keeping the enum approach because I suspect the cost of the switch to be higher than directly calling the relevant method. My computeSomething() method is going to be called several million times, maybe 10 or 100 million times.

Comment: switch is very efficient in term of speed. I don't think you will notice any differences between both approaches. (it's more a matter of style/taste) (IMHO keeping enum small and concise increase readability)

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Here's an alternative that avoids creating and then hashing strings.

```
private static Category[] CATEGORIES = {
        MMM, MMO, MMP, MOM, MOO, MOP, MPM, MPO, MPP,
        OMM, OMO, OMP, OOM, OOO, OOP, OPM, OPO, OPP,
        PMM, PMO, PMP, POM, POO, POP, PPM, PPO, PPP
};

private int toTernary(int x) {
    // (This method will probably be in-lined ...)
    if (x < 0) return 0;
    else if (x == 0) return 1;
    else return 2;
}

private Category init(int i, int, j, int k) {
    int index = 9 * toTernary(i) + 3 * toTernary(j) + toTernary(k);
    return CATEGORIES[i];
}
```

Q2: You could build an array of "algorithm" objects, indexed by the ordinal of the `Category` values.

Comment: As enums are also accessible via their index, this method could also be used with an enum instead of an array: return Category.values()[i]

Comment: Yea ... however,  that would  make the lookup dependent on the order of the `enum` values.  Also, I have a suspicion that `Category.values()` returns a *fresh copy* of an array.

Answer (score 0):

May I point you in the direction of the switch statement?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

I have used it numerous times to get rid of pesky if chains

Comment: Yes ... but how would you use it in this context?